# Imagemagick add shadow to trimmed photo

Tags: imagemagick

in ImageMagicK, I trimmed a photo according a Mask image, But how to add Shadow to the trimmed Photo?
please refer to the [example](http://s7d3.scene7.com/is/image/TOP/3283_LL35995WHLB2zm?wid=400&mask=CR6.25x6.25_Vdw&effect=-1&op_blur=15&opac=50&pos=9,15)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's a tutorial on shadows at the imagemagick ["Usage" page](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#shadow), with demonstration of the "-shadow" option.